# Copy char* to tchar*

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to point a char* to a tchar* that is inside of a struct.

```
typedef struct data {
    int count;
    TCHAR* msg;
    COLORREF colour;
} DATA, *PDATA; // DATA non-pointer, PDATA pointer

pdata = (PDATA)malloc(sizeof(pdata));
pdata->colour = RGB(255, 0, 0);
pdata->msg = (TCHAR*)malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * 20);
// copy tchar to tchar in pdata->msg
// I have tried _tcscpy and _tcscpy_s but it is not working
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG)pdata);
```

Then I am trying to get the data through

```
(PDATA)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
```

This is being called in a separate file and then used to show the text on the screen

Comment: so, can you show your copying of strings ?

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use the C tag instead of C++?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(pdata));` would allocate space for a pointer, not for the struct.

Comment: Fixed! The pdata = (PDATA)malloc(sizeof(DATA)); was the problem

Comment: Thank you @BoPersson that fixed it

Comment: @SpencerPollock: your title says you want to copy a `char*` into a `TCHAR*`, but your code example says you want to copy a `TCHAR*` into a `TCHAR*` instead. Those are two very different things. If you want to copy a `char*`, and `TCHAR*` map to `char*` (`UNICODE` *is not* defined), you can copy as-is. But if `TCHAR*` maps to `wchar_t*` (`UNICODE` *is* defined), you cannot copy as-is, you have to perform a runtime data conversion instead using `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent.